# My Sallen Key Butterworth high pass filter's frequency response graph is not responding

Tags: proteus, frequency-response, high-pass-filter, graph, sallen-key

[image]I tried to make a cutoff frequency of interface in partial discharge but the response frequency graph is not responding.

[image: 08**hi, I tried to make a cutoff frequency of interface in partial discharge but the response frequency graph is not responding. 1]

I already changed (Amplitude= & frequency= 50Hz) in the sine generator properties and DC generator properties in both U1. I measured frequency response in Vout. What should I do?

Comment: A better resolution picture would be useful. For instance, it looks like the final op-amp feedback isn't properly connected.

Comment: `but the response frequency graph is not responding.` What does that mean? Are you saying that you're performing a frequency sweep and you don't see anything? If that's the case, then are you sure you're measuring at the appropriate location?

Comment: I learned from YouTube, they put Vin and Vout for the frequency response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (red circle) appears to indicate a connection problem: -

[image]

In other words, the crossed wires should be connected.

Comment: @ADORINA if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.